# Pyinstaller: Positional Argument follows keyword argument

Tags: tkinter, pyinstaller, ttk

Before marking this as duplicate please read my question.

This is my spec file which has a dependency on tkbootstrap

```
    block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['gui.py'],
             pathex=['P:\\clgProject'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('themes.json', 'ttkbootstrap'), ('Symbola.ttf','ttkbootstrap')], ["K-Level.txt"], ["Mark Distrubtion.txt"],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='gui',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

Unlike the other similar question, my spec file doesnt have a `exclude_binaries=True` .
When i try to run `pyinstaller gui.spec`, it shows the error

```
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Look at your `datas` in your `Analysis(...)`. Is it supposed to be like that? What is it supposed to be like? A list of tuples?

Comment: There is a function call like this somewhere in your code: `func(..., param="value", other_value, ...)`. Here, `other_value` is the positional argument following the keyword argument (`param="value"`).